# How to disable php language extension (eg. abc.php.fr)?

Tags: php, apache

by default apache will load php interpreter with .php extension. Somep\how php interpreter also called with this kind of extension .php.fr . How to disable this language extension?

Answer (score 1):

The `.fr` is being interpreted as French during content negotiation by Apache. This is probably because you have `Options +MultiViews` and `MultiviewsMatch Handlers` are both set. Getting rid of either should stop `.php.fr` from working, but changing this may break other pages. (Assumably, you enabled both for a reason). Also, I'm not completely sure if `MultiVideosMatch` applies to PHP, but `Options +MultiViews` definitely does.

If you're trying to make sure people can't upload PHP files and have your webserver execute them, instead of just blacklisting extensions, use `php_admin_flag engine off` to turn off PHP in that location:

```
<Location /uploads>
    php_admin_flag engine off
</Location>
```

Comment: i tried to remove MultiViews , still no effects and i dont have MultiviewMatch configured. Calling directly in url file.php.fr will eventually execute the php file. For certain reason disabling php engine is not an option for me. Any idea?

Comment: Did you actually try `Options -MultiViews` to make sure it is off?

Answer (score -2):

you can setup the extensions interpreted by Apache on 2 Places.

1. httpd.conf

   AddType application/x-httpd-php .phpx

Will load .phpx files as PHP Scripts

2. mime.type

   application/x-httpd-php phpx

Comment: (a) AddType can be in any apache config file, and there are normally many. (b) There isn't going to be an AddType for .php.fr. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html